# Why doesn't Android's WebView load some URLs?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

My `WebView` doesn't show some URLs especially if it has the leading `www.` part missing. `http://google.com` doesn't load but `http://www.google.com` loads just fine. I don't get any exceptions or messages in the logcat so it seems rather hard to find out what's going on behind the scenes. Here's the snippet that actually displays my `WebView`.

```
WebView wbvBrowser = new WebView(this.objContext);
wbvBrowser.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
wbvBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wbvBrowser.loadUrl("http://google.com");
```

Would any of you know what's causing this issue? I'm baffled.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Enable DOM Storage APIs

```
wbvBrowser.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the app has permission to access the Internet. Add the following to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: The OP clearly said that http://www.google.com loads just fine, which means that the app has internet permissions.

Comment: @osmank, Guess I missed that, but it is a common problem to encounter and it appears a few people have found my answer helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
wbvBrowser.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
private class Callback extends WebViewClient{  //HERE IS THE MAIN CHANGE. 

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return (false);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey Aditya, would be able to explain what this does and how it resolves my issue? I'll give it a shot though.

Comment: Didn't help. ..but I did see two messages in the Logcat. `I/SqliteDatabaseCpp: sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at line 27699 of [8609a15dfa], db=/data/data/com.example.testapp/databases/webview.db`. I can't understand what it is that it is trying to open.

Comment: Your webview database files are corrupted... delete this files and also add the code i am pasting below...

Comment: I tried uninstalling my application but the issue is still there. Any more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: Add an 's' to the http. Make it https

```
wbvBrowser.loadUrl("https://google.com");
```